# Using rcmd(remote command) on Windows with Python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, logic

So I am trying to use either `os` or `subprocess` to open a rcmd session and login to a remote server via DNS name. This is on a Windows 10 machine. The problem I am having is getting the rcmd session to take the server name. My code is:

```
import os
os.system("C:/location/of/rcmd.exe, dnsname")
```

Or

```
p = Popen([r'C:/location/of/rcmd.exe', 'dnsname'], shell = True, stdin=PIPE, 
          stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = p.stdout.read()
print(output)
```

My results are:

"Usage: rcmd [server_name [command] ]

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. If I put in a character (in this case a '-') in front of the server name, the the response is:

"Unknown switch -dnsname"

Can someone provide some insight on what is the proper way to enter in an argument for that dns name? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I figured it out. The dns server name requires two back slashes (\) for it to work. I then added four back slashes to the server name (\\dnsname) and I was able to log in properly. Thanks cco for your reply and the hit to remove the comma.

Comment: Have you tried it without the comma?

Comment: Yes, and I get the same as the first result. I tried the '&' and a semi colon and it gives me the same. I've also used subprocess and when it prints out I get the same result.